# Mac Terminal: Repeat Multiple Previous Commands Sequentially

Tags: terminal, osx, macintosh

I know that I can navigate through previous commands using the up & down arrow keys, making it easy to re-run an earlier line of code. However if I want to re-run multiple sequential commands I need to navigate back with the arrow keys for each line, which can get kind of cumbersome if I have entered many lines of code in between.

In Windows Command Prompt, one you have navigated back to a previous line of code & pressed enter to re-run it, you can simply press the down arrow key to get to the line which followed the original command. This makes it easy to run a sequence of commands from earlier in the session.

I know the Mac Terminal has lots of nice features & hotkeys so surely there must be some way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `history`, you will see a numbered list of previous commands.  If you want, say, to run commands 123, 124, and 125 in sequence from your history, you can do this:

```
$ !123; !124; !125
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what I'm looking for, but it seems like it may be as close as I'm going to get. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you're finding yourself running the same commands again and again, you might put them into a script:

```
$ echo "!123 && !124 && !125" > my_cool_script.sh
$ chmod +x my_cool_script.sh
$ ./my_cool_script.sh
```